# Advanced search text box (search through multivalued column)

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to create a filtering search box that can search through a multivalued column? For instance, I have a column called languages, and for each cell it may contain more than 1 language (eg, english, chinese, japanese). So when I search for english and japanese in the search box it will return the rows that contain these words.

```
Private sub txtquicksearch_Change()
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim sSearch As String
If Me.txtquicksearch.Text Then
    sSearch = "'*" & Replace(Me.txtquicksearch.Text, "'", "''") & "*'"
    strFilter = "[languages] Like " & sSearch & ""
   Me.[Languages Subform].Form.Filter = strFilter
   Me.[Languages Subform].Form.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: Is this multi-value column a comma separated string or is it a Multi-Value Field? You want to search for multiple languages at same time?

Comment: Why the Replace to escape apostrophe? Why would data have apostrophes?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a truly Multi-Value type field and search for a single language selected in a combobox, consider:

```
Me.[Languages Subform] = "ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tablename WHERE Languages.Value = '" & Me.cbxLanguage & "')"
```

This gets more complicated if want to search for multiple languages at once. Use a multi-select listbox for selecting languages and VBA that constructs selections into an array list (common topic and should be able to find example code). Array list for text values looks like `"English","Japanese"` - yes, quote marks (or apostrophes) must part of the construct. Use that list:

```
Me.[Languages Subform] = "ID IN (SELECT ID FROM tablename WHERE Languages.Value IN (" & strList & "))"
```